# How do I switch text in a div from 'dark' and 'light' back and forth when i click it in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm making a page color toggle for my website and I want to change from using two different radio buttons to a `div` that you click to toggle the color. I also need the text in the `div` to change:

```js
var theme = new Vue({
    el: '#theme',
    data: {
        picked: local?.theme || 'default',
    },
    watch: {
        picked: function (val) {
            if (val == 'Dark') {
                local.theme = 'dark';
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg", "black");
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", "white");
            } else if (val == 'Light') {
                local.theme = 'light';
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg", "rgb(206, 206, 206)");
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", "black");
            }
            if (cookies) {
                localStorage.setItem("siteData", JSON.stringify(local));
            }
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="theme">
    <span>Chose the color theme you want (works now)</span>
    <br>
    <div>Dark/Light toggle</div>
    <input type="radio" id="dark" value="Dark" v-model="picked">
    <label for="dark">Dark</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="light" value="Light" v-model="picked">
    <label for="light">Light</label>
    <br><br>
    <span>Current Mode: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't work with DOM directly, this is no vue way.

Try to wrap your elements with a class bound to your picked property :

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#theme',
    data: {
        picked: 'default'
    }
});
```

```css
.dark{
  background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="theme" v-bind:class="picked">
    <span>Chose the color theme you want (works now)</span>
    <br>
    <div>Dark/Light toggle</div>
    <input type="radio" id="dark" value="dark" v-model="picked">
    <label for="dark">Dark</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="light" value="light" v-model="picked">
    <label for="light">Light</label>
    <br><br>
    <span>Current Mode: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

If you need to change the view (condition) of the parent component, you can connect `npm install vuex --save` and reactively change the view via shared storage just like now using data.picked.